# Do geographic features like large lakes or a moraine make it more difficult to predict precipitation?

Tags: weather-forecasting, precipitation

I've noticed that Environment Canada's precipitation forecasts for the Great Lakes region (east of Toronto) are usually one of the following:

- 30% rain
- 40% rain
- 60% rain
- 70% rain

But not usually higher than 70%.

---

Whereas, I've heard the forecast in the prairies (Winnipeg) often have a higher certainty, such as:

- 80% rain
- 90% rain

---

That makes me wonder:

Is it easier to make high-certainty precipitation predictions in places like the prairies  vs. the Great Lakes region?

For example, would Lake Ontario and/or the Oak Ridges Moraine make it harder to predict precipitation in the Great Lakes region — since inbound storms might be affected by those features?

Comment: It's not a confidence in the forecast, it's the Probability of Precipitation (PoP). If it's 50 %, there is 1 in 2 chance that a significant amount of rain will fall over the considered area during the considered time interval. So if you see higher values in a region, it just means that this region gets more rain, not that the forecast there is more reliable.

Comment: @user1974 Forecasts are a spuious way to understand's one weather. Why not understand your weather or climate through past records first and then use that to validate your forecasts ?  In your case you should google for mesoscale meteorology and search for lake effect rain